# UITextView inside a UITableViewCell, how to resign textview's firstResponder when tableView scrolls?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, first-responder

I created a custom `UITableViewCell`, and a `UITextView` was put inside this prototype cell. When I click on this textView, keyboard can bounce automatically. However, if I want to hide the keyboard, I will have to click `Return` key. It isn't quite convenient.

Here's the question.
How can I resign the textView's `firstResponder` for hiding the keyboard when I scroll the tableview.

`cellForRowAtIndex` method is below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("InputCell")!
        let textView = cell.viewWithTag(102) as! UITextView
        textView.editable = true
        textView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.targetForAction(#selector(FeedBackViewController.getTextViewInsideCell(_:)), withSender: textView)
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 1){
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ConfirmButtonCell")!
        let label = cell.textLabel
        label?.text = "send"
        label?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    return cell
}
```

Here are some methods I have implemented.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool{
    if(text == "\n"){
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

And I have no idea how to implement this method.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

}
```

Comment: `self.view.endEditing(true)` in your `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` will do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try implement this on `viewDidLoad`, it will auto dismiss keyboard when tableview start dragging:

`tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive` or `.OnDrag`

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` inherited from `UIScrollView` that conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegateProtocol`. Try to override `scrollViewDidScroll` function from it and resign first responder from textview.

Be sure to assign tableView's delegate to your view controller, and then add the following code

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    yourTextView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

As per [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:) `scrollViewDidScroll`

> Tells the delegate when the user scrolls the content view within the receiver.

**Update**

Another approach to resign first responder is to set `endEditing` to `true` for your view:

> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: How would he access the instance of textView which is inside a tableViewCell?

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it too, but in this way, I can't get textView `yourTextView`inside the cell and resign it.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan I hope you aren't going to show a method which goes around getting the instance of cell from IndexPath and then access its subviews? A simpler solution would be to call `self.view.endEditing(true)` in the scroll method.

Comment: By the way, first answer has resolved my problem. Thanks for your advice too~

Comment: @NSNoob exactly - that was my second hint with end editing :)

Comment: @MangoRyan - awesome, now you know at least 4 ways of how to resign first responder! Thats great!

Answer (score 1):

it is quite easy  You can do same with storyboard too

open storyboard

select tableview  or collection view

and select  on Drag
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Same as first Answer~

Comment: it is little different @MangoRyan , he answered do it programatically and i show you in storyboard :)